# Layer positron of Carto DB

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I tried to add the layer made by Carto DB with OpenStreetMap data : 'Positron'.

I've OpenLayers3, and I found the code in the page of the website of CartoDB : http://cartodb.com/basemaps

So, I added the code  to my Javascript,

```
var cartodb_positron        = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                    url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                                    attributions:   [
                                        new ol.Attribution({ html: ['&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>']})
                                                    ]
                                    })});
```

After I added my layer to the map

```
var map = 
    new ol.Map  ({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [cartodb_positron,vector_limit,vector_point],
        interactions: map_interactions,
        controls: map_controles,
        view: new ol.View({zoom: 11.20,minZoom: 11.20,maxZoom: 15, center: transform([1403000,2251475,1403000,2251475]),extent: transform([1380000,2211450, 1420157,2250936])})
                });
```

And finally my map have no mapbase, but only the vector layers... and Mozilla firebug said anything.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the response !

It's not

```
url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

But It's

```
url: 'http://s.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```